# How would I output an Weekly Opening hours from a single array in two table columns

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I have an array with the following array structure (for $openingHours) that holds the data for opening and closing hours. For each brand there could be a possible 14 (although some may just have 7 for seven days) opening times [Hour Type 1 or Hour Type 2].

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [day] => Mon
            [open_time] => 08:30:00
            [close_time] => 19:00:00
            [hour_type] => 1
            [brand_id] => 4
        )
    [7] => Array
        (
            [day] => Mon
            [open_time] => 08:00:00
            [close_time] => 18:00:00
            [hour_type] => 2
            [brand_id] => 4
        )
)
```

I am trying to output this into a table of the following structure:

```
<div class="table">
<div class="thead">
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="th">Day</div>
        <div class="th">Type 1</div>
        <div class="th">Type 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tbody">
    <div class="tr">
        <?php            
        foreach($openingHours as $openingHour) {
            // Check opening hour brand id against the parent brand id to display
            // opening hours just for the correct brand
            if ($openingHour['$brand_id'] == $brand['brand_id']) {
               echo "<div class='td'>" . $openingHour["day"]. "</div>";
                if ($openingHour['hour_type'] == 1){
                    echo "<div class='td'>" . $openingHour["open_time"] . "-" . $openingHour["close_time"] . "</div>";
                }
                if ($openingHour['hour_type'] == 2){
                    echo "<div class='td'>" . $openingHour["open_time"] . "-" . $openingHour["close_time"] . "</div>";
                }                    
                echo "</div><div class='tr'>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>       
</div>
```

But the above code simply outputs the hours for 'Type 1' and 'Type 2' Hour in the first . What am I missing here and I wonder if there is a 'better' way to achieve this?

Comment: Just a note, you are assigning classes to your divs that mimic a table, is there any reason here not to use the classic html table, as the data you are trying to display is tabular?

Comment: Mainly because we are trying to not use any html table anywhere but specifically because we were not certain how the layout would be and hence a little less rewrite if we did use a not so tabular layout but in terms of the initial question, the issue remains even with classic html table.